# How to get the current build version in Maven/Tycho

Tags: maven, tycho

I have read that the `${project.version}` property should be used to obtain the *full version* of a project.

But if I use this property in a build to pass the currently built version to an external build process, its values is alway `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` where I would need something like `1.0.0-20160220-1234`. The phase in which the external build step is called is `package´.

The `tycho-packaging-plugin` is configured to produce timestamps like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</format>
</configuration>
```

And the resulting artifacts do have timestamps in the versions/names

I use Maven 3.3.3 with [Eclipse Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/) 0.24, however, with previous versions of Tycho the behavior is the same. Not sure if Tycho behaves differently than plain Maven in this regard.

The build is run with

```
mvn clean verify
```

in the directory of the master pom.

The actual project I am using this for is [Extras for Eclipse](https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/pom.xml). The external build step is invoked [in line 129 of the 'repository' child pom](https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/com.codeaffine.extras.repository/pom.xml#L129).

I have also used the echo plug-in in the above-mentioned child pom to diagnose the problem like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>echo</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <echos>
      <echo>actual version: ${project.version}</echo>
    </echos>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The output is the same as the external build receives: `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

What do I need to do or which property do I need to use to get the qualified version of the current build?

Comment: Can you please show how you are doing this? Via command line? Which Maven version do you use? Which tycho version do you use? Can you show an example project which does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding the `${project.version}` property should hold the qualified version, e.g. `1.0.0-20160218-1234`. But either there is a bug in Maven/Tycho or my understanding is plain wrong. And I would be happy if someone could clarify this.

However, I found the `${qualifiedVersion}` property that is set by the [tycho-packaging:build-qualifier](https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/build-qualifier-mojo.html) mojo. This property holds the expected value.

Note that even though the documentation states

> is assigned to the project property `qualifiedVersion`

the property cannot be accessed through `${project.qualifiedVersion}`. It needs to be referenced as `${qualifiedVersion}`.

Comment: Q: From my understanding the ${project.version} property should hold the qualified version, e.g. 1.0.0-20160218-1234  ... A:  I don't think so. the ${project.version} is the version as parsed in the pom model, so it's the one which contains -SNAPSHOT. It is resolved later to something more specific, that -as you noticed- is then injected in the ${qualifiedVersion} property. But the ${project.version} is not (and should not be as per Maven rules) modified compared to initial value from the model.